# Play music in background in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-player

I am streaming music file using AVAudioPlayer, It plays fine in background if i use nib file but when i try the same code using storyboard, The music playing stoped. I can't understand the reason why its stop playing in background when i using storyboard.

i am using this code for it

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[audioPlayer setVolume:0.1];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Can any help me to play it in background using storyboard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
@implementation YourViewController
{
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

// if your are using ARC, after exiting this method, system will kill your audioPlayer. This is the reason why you can not play the music. 
// in your method:
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
```